# Convert vba to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba

I have an Access2003 database which has a table linked in from a SQL Server database. I have this Access vba that updates a column in that SQL Server table. Each month that table gets cleared and a new set of records is imported, the amount of records ranges from 300,000 to 
450,000 each monthly.

This Access vba code runs but takes 5+ hours. I need to do something about that, anyone have any ideas of how to speed this up? One idea I had was to convert this to a stored procedure on the SQL Server but I have no idea how to write that so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

bobh.

VBA code:

```
' update the ID field in the import table 
Dim intCounter As Double 
Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("tblMarsImport", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges) 

MyRec.MoveFirst 
intCounter = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "000001" 

Do While Not MyRec.EOF 
   MyRec.Edit 
   MyRec!MarsID = CStr(intCounter) 
   MyRec.Update 
   MyRec.MoveNext 
   intCounter = intCounter + 1 
Loop 

MyRec.Close
```

Comment: You could speed this up even sticking with Access, look at changing your code from **DAO** to **ADODB**, and use a **Transaction** to only perform the writing action minimal times, 300K+ will be too high so do a **Commit** every 65K.

Comment: I suspect something like `Update <table> set <column> = <date_formated> + ROW_NUMBER OVER(ORDER BY <column>)' [see MSDN for Row_Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).  But you'll need some formatting code in there.

Comment: Import the data into the table and then add idcolumn `alter table [yourtable] add ID int identity (1,1)`  This is going to be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Result int
SELECT @Result = (SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats 
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('tblMarsImport')    
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1))
SELECT @Result

SET I=1
REPEAT
Update tblMarsImport set MarsID = Cast(Replace(Convert(varchar(10), Date, 120), '-', '') As int)
 + RIGHT('00000' + I, 6)

  SET I=I+1
UNTIL I>@Result
```

You may need to tweak the date a bit, but that should get you really close.

EDIT: On second thought, you'll need an Identity column in your table (similar to an AutoNumber field in Access) so you can select the ID of the record you're updating by using a WHERE clause in the Update command.  Otherwise, it'll just keep updating the same record over and over.

Comment: my table(tblMarsImport) does have an identity field called ImpID but I would not know how to use that in a where clause in the Update statement. Can you help?

Comment: Try something like this (and you may need to mess with it a bit):

Update tblMarsImport set MarsID = Cast(Replace(Convert(varchar(10), Date, 120), '-', '') As int)
 + RIGHT('00000' + I, 6) WHERE ImpID = I

The idea is, you have to tell it which record to update, and using an Identity field will always only look at a single record because that Identity field MUST be unique.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Row_number in order to keep track of which row you are currently looping through. This way you will not need to add a new column  to your table.
[Documentation for row number][1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx